# Что значит селектор '>'?

Tags: html, css

Встретил такую строку, и не могу понять что это такое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Upvote + почистил вопрос от своих неактуальных комментариев, рекомендую и вам поудалять ненужные комменты.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В CSS - это [Селектор дочерних элементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Дословно `html > body` значит

> Элемент `body`, являющийся прямым потомком `html`

Answer (score 1):

обращение именно к элементу Body.